# Is it possible to install a virtual machine under Linux that looks like a Windows machine to IT?

Tags: linux, windows, virtualization, dell

I'm on a corporate network with a homogeneous Windows setup for all Dell workstations. They use KBOX to manage the workstations. I want to set up my machine to run several VMs under Linux instead, but they're concerned that this will make them unable to manage the workstation with KBOX, resulting in having to eventually wipe it and install the standard Windows workstation on this machine.

Is it possible to set up this Dell workstation with Linux so that they can still manage it? E.g. with a virtual Windows install. Including letting them shut it down and start it, install Windows updates, firmware upgrades, etc.

Comment: I think this comes under what questions not to ask, "Licensing, legal advice, and circumvention of security or policy".

Comment: Instead of attempting to bypass IT, contact them, discuss your needs as a user, and work *with* them to address your issues.

Comment: It also doesn't really comply with the intent of the site from that FAQ, that this site is for professional IT workers.

Comment: Don't be cynical. In talking to them, they say that as long as they can manage the machine the same way as all the others, it should be fine. But I don't know that they can. Do you?

Comment: This is a site for **professional systems administrators**. Not for people to get advice on how to subvert the policy that's been created by those systems administrators. Ask them nicely and explain why you want to do what you want to do. If they say no, ask your manager to deal with it. Don't blatantly subvert policy. That's how people get fired.

Comment: Oh, do cheer up.

Comment: Apocalisp - your phrasing absolutely does sound like you're trying to subvert corporate IT, not work with them. Your comments show differently, but your question (as asked) sounds like behavior that no one on this site would want to encourage.

Comment: depends what needs to be managed the linux host or the windows vm's? There is nothing that will prevent them from using kbox to manage the windows based vm's but the most likely won't be able to manage the linux hosts. Caveat I don't know anything about kbox...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you should do is describe your needs to IT and see if they can work with you on this. You can run VMware Workstation or even the free VMware Player and make VMs under the corporate Windows load.

Comment: That's a good idea. Make the host machine the Windows box and run virtual Linux and Windows machines under that!

Answer (score 0):

Based on the presumption that there is a Windows domain and you are not a domain admin, no.